# How to get the difference between the current time zone and GMT

Tags: php, timezone, dst

I know you can get the difference (in seconds) between the servers time zone and GMT time using:

```
$diff = date("Z");
```

Is there a way to get the same thing, but for a specific date.  For example if DST ends next Sunday, but I need to set a time in GMT for next Tuesday.  How can I check the timezone offset for next Tuesday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the second parameter for date for this.

```
 date('Z', strtotime("2013-08-27"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DateTime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)

```
$dt = new DateTime('2013-12-01'); // <-- any date after DST ends
echo $dt->format('Z');
```